# How can I locate the HMTL or Class definitions of a particular template on my wordpress site?

Tags: html

I'm using a WP theme and want to simply rename a label. The search query shows 'search jobs' whereas I want 'search' only.

Here is a link to the page:

https://serialphotography.com/events/?search_keywords=Circle&search_location=&search_category=

I've accessed the theme editor in WP but this only shows the PHP files, I believe the PHP calls on the HTML. In file editor on my cpanel, under the theme, I can only see a list of php files. I've done an overall search of the div class and still cannot find it.

Comment: possibly from the plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-job-manager/ - please ask in their forum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to wordpress development. :)

So most content that's visible from your browser is generated from a combination of two things:

- The Database (MySQL)
- The PHP Application (Wordpress)

Wordpress reaches out to the database and passes the relevant data to the appropriate function to create the pages you see.

In order to change the text you're seeing, you need to know whether that text primarily lives in the database (Like a setting for a plugin) or if it's scripted. (Generated by PHP on the server)

From looking through the resources served on that page, I can tell that you're using this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-job-manager/

If the plugin is well designed (from their site it appears to be well documented), then you ought to be able to leverage wordpress functionality to get what you want.

Unfortunately, without more information regarding your setup and this page, there's little more I can do to help you other than make an educated guess. We're lacking critical information like what the page content is, if you're using a template file, if you're in a child-theme, if this is built into the theme, etc.

From what I can gather from the plugin's site, it would appear that the page listing is being added to your page using the `[jobs]` shortcode for the plugin? If this is the case, then you can EASILY override the contents by creating a new template file.

---

**Create a new template file**

To create the template file, first add the following line to your theme's functions.php 
`add_theme_support( 'job-manager-templates' );`
This will enable support for the template you're going to make in your theme.

Then, create a new file called `job-filters.php` and upload it to `your-theme/job_manager/`. This will be empty at the moment, but we'll use the code from the original plugin, then you can edit that code however you wish.

So, then duplicate the code from `wordpress-site.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-job-manager/templates/job-filters.php` and paste it into the new file.

You should now be able to edit the contents of that form.

Just look for

```
<input type="submit" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search Jobs', 'wp-job-manager' ); ?>">
```

Change the value to what you want.

Keep in mind, that this means that you're OVERRIDING the template used by the plugin, so you may need to manually update this template if it's changed by the plugin in a future update.

Good luck!

(Tested on localhost to confirm solution. 2020-02-01)